# Only single properties can be saved

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-php-ogm

I have the following "User" class:

```
<?php

use GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Annotations as OGM;

/**
 * @OGM\Node(label="User")
 */

class User {
    /**
     * @OGM\GraphID
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    /*
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

    /*
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function __construct($username, $password) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /*
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to work with it, as shown:

```
>>> require_once 'User.php'
=> 1
>>> use GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\EntityManager;
=> null
>>> $manager = EntityManager::create('http://neo4j:superstrongpassword@localhost:7474');
=> GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\EntityManager {#171
     +"annotationDriver": GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Mapping\AnnotationDriver {#178},
   }
>>> $x = new User('foo', 'bar');
=> User {#217}
>>> $manager->persist($x)
=> null
>>> $manager->flush()
=> null
```

However, if I run the following query in Neo4j "browser", I can just see the following being created:

```
$ match (x) return x
Rows
x: username:    foo
```

Creation of the other properties are seemingly skipped.

I believe I'm missing something pretty basic; what is the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docblocks for the password @Property annotation are missing a `*`:

```
    /*
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;
```

The first line : `/*` should be with two stars `/**`

```
    /**
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
```